# Inheritance in Waterline ORM

Tags: javascript, node.js, inheritance, waterline

Does the Waterline ORM support inheritance? Say, I have a model called `BusinessDocument`, and I want to create a new model called `SalesOrder` that extends `BusinessDocument`. So, `SalesOrder` should end up having all the attributes of `BusinessDocument` plus some new attributes. Is this supported by Waterline?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it isn't supported out-of-the-box by Waterline. See this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/issues/126).

One of the comments in the above issue also links to a sailscast video on YouTube ([here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=038CRoDLU7o)). In a nutshell, the video walks through using [lodash](https://lodash.com/) to [merge](https://lodash.com/docs#merge) the child model with the base model, like so:

baseModel.js

```
module.exports = {
  attributes : {
    name : 'STRING',
    age  : 'INTEGER'
  },
  foo : function () {}
}
```

childModel.js

```
var baseModel = require('/path/to/baseModel')
  , _ = require('lodash')

module.exports = _.merge(baseModel, {
  attributes : {
    birthDate : 'DATE',
    ...
  }
})
```

Comment: The only problem with this is that it actually creates a baseModel collection and childModel collection, thus not being able to do `BaseModel.find()` and get childmodel records too. It can be - kind of - solved by adding `tableName:"baseModel"`, but it isn't supported in all adapters.

Comment: True. You may end up having to call ```find``` on each of the child models separately.